# Apple push notification - как правильно отобразить нужный контроллер?

Tags: objective-c, ios, apple, ios7

Доброе время суток! В общем столкнулся с проблемой, приходит уведомление, скажем "Вам пришло новое сообщение", мне необходимо открыть чат с этим пользователем, но что бы попасть в чат, нужно прочти 3 экрана от стартового, либо же пользователь не выходит с приложения, а заблокировал телефон на контроллере чата, подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом нужно/можно/будет правильно открывать нужный контроллер? Если к нему нужно добиратся через 3-9 земель? или не наоборот?

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Ой вопрос красивый за плюсую.

Comment: не знаю актуально ли еще, но если вдруг: вам надо просто произвести навигацию на заранее известный контроллер, или вам надо, чтобы в зависимости от содержания push notification открывался заранее неизвестный контроллер?

Answer (score 3):

Думаю здесь больше зависит от архитектуры приложения. Вот у меня, например, несколько NavigationControllers и у каждого есть переход в чат. Дак контрол чата принимает на вход модель собеседников и таким образом я могу его вызвать в любом месте через пуш, сформулировав перед этим все модели данных для чат контрола.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    NotificationViewController *notificationViewController = [[NotificationViewController alloc] init];
    [navController.visibleViewController.navigationController pushViewController:notificationViewController];    
}
```

Но в этом примере я пушаюсь сразу же в чат без промежуточных экранов. Если же задача стоит именно пропушиться туда где чат пройдя по промежуточным экраном, то тут нужно придумать какой-нибудь алгоритм переходов с неким path пушей экранов с анимацией, с блоком завершения анимации и пушингом следующего контрола в path . В общем много вариантов, на самом деле, все зависит от ТЗ.

Comment: @Bimawa

На данный момент есть 5 контроллеров, 0 - навигационный, остальные информационные, все проходят от 1 до 5го, каким образом можно открыть чат так, что бы пользователь потом смог вернуться на 1 или 2 (на любой контроллер)?

Comment: Если базовый контроллер UINavigationController то можно сетапнуть массив всех контроллов через метод:

    - (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated

Comment: @Bimawa, А что это за контроллер такой (NotificationViewController)?

Comment: Это некий контроллер в который вы хотите перейти.. Например чат.

Comment: Я использую библиотеку, для левого меню (слайдом) и такой способ как показали вы приводит к фатальной ошибке

Comment: @dev_nikita_ysacov

Что вы используете?

Comment: @dev_nikita_ysacov мой пример только показывает как работает переход. Он индивидуальный для каждого проекта. Тупо скопировать тут не пройдет, нужно понять как все работает и все встанет на свои места. Для начала напишите метод при вызове которого вы перейдете в 5 контроллер програмно. Затем заталкайте вызов этого метода в `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` PROFIT